# Two Layouts on Android Screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make an application that will have a set of screens that are similar in the fact that they will have a layout at the top, and at the bottom will have a set of buttons. Basically what happens is that one of the buttons at the bottom is a spinner, and each of the options that gets selected should inflate a layout into the top half of the screen, while leaving all of the buttons at the bottom.

What is the best way of going about this, without having to rewrite the part of the xml for the buttons at the bottom of the screen.

[image: Screen Shot]
From the image above, I need the five buttons at the bottom to stay the same for all screens, while everything above it needs to be changed when one of the options is selected from the spinner.

My code currently is as follows: It currently puts up the buttons at the bottom, and the text in the red box, which will be on every screen. What I need to do is inflate the personal layout into the space in between.
    setContentView(R.layout.people1);

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.service_user_button)
{
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.people_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                getBaseContext(), R.array.service_user_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want your layout to look something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/theContent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </ScrollView>

    <!-- Buttons go inside this -->        
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

         />

</LinearLayout>
```

At runtime you lookup the LinearLayout with the id 'theContent' and assign it's children to it.

Comment: So basically, I should have one huge xml file with all the different layouts, and select the one that I need at runtime? or are you saying that I can have all those LinearLayouts in separate xml files?

Comment: You don't need it to be a huge file. You can use a [ViewStub](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) that references the second layout. It will be inflated when it becomes visible or inflate() is called.

Comment: And you can always use the <include>-tag if you need to separate stuff for readability and reuse.

Comment: Yes you have separate XML files. You can inflate and attach them on demand.

Comment: Have you got any code examples for inflating and attaching the LinearLayouts in separate files?

Comment: To inflate a layout: View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.whatever, null);

Comment: To attach it to a parent use ViewGroup.addView(). All the Layout types are ViewGroups.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `<include>` tag. Check [this](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/25/android-layout-trick-2-include-to-reuse/) explanation by Romain Guy.

Answer (score 0):

There exists one more additional (not alternative!) possibility. The whole activity screen is always inserted into a FrameLayout. So, you can use as a root layout Merge instead of a root layout. The layout with buttons will have large top margin, so they will be placed at the bottom. Other layouts will be at the top, as they are. The theory is described [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html).

Of course, the common bottom layout should be placed into include.